# Merge two "list in list" in scheme

Tags: list, merge, scheme

I don't know how to exactly express my question in language. Pardon my ambiguous words in the title

My question is:

If you have

> a = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]....], b = [[1, 3], [4, 8], ....]

How to merge a and b like

```
[[1,2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [1, 3], [4, 8]....]
```

in scheme??

I have already tried using car or write a function my self to solve it, but all failed. I was thinking to use (cons a b), but it'll give me [[[1, 2], [3, 4]...], [[1, 3], [4, 8]...]] which is not what I want.
I tried to write a recursive function, but still I'll get the similar trouble as (cons a b)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us what you tried so far? From what you posted it seems you don't even know how lists look like in Scheme :)

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for `append`.  In general, you want `(<some-function> '(a b c ... l m n) '(o p q ... x y z))` to return `'(a b c ... l m n o p q ... x y z)`, yes?  That function is usually called `append`.   E.g., `(append '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6)) '((1 3) (4 8))) => ((1 2) (3 4) (5 6) (1 3) (4 8))`.

Comment: Yeah, but it's easy to merge two lists of numbers, but I'm really stuck at merging two lists of list. I was thinking (cons a b), but this will give you [[[1,2], [3, 4]....] [[1,3], [4,8]...]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you're looking for [`append`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._append%29%29). This is how the code in the question would look like in Scheme:

```
(define a '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6)))
(define b '((1 3) (4 8)))

(append a b)
=> '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6) (1 3) (4 8))
```

If you want to implement your own version of `append` it's simple enough:

```
(define (my-append lst1 lst2)
  (if (null? lst1)
      lst2
      (cons (car lst1)
            (my-append (cdr lst1) lst2))))

(my-append a b)
=> '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6) (1 3) (4 8))
```